# Can't connect to remote Oracle server using ADO.Net | Connection string error?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, system.data.oracleclient

I have been trying to connect to an Oracle server using the following connection string:

```
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.206.0.23)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = ORCLWEX3)
    )
 )
;User Id= RAMNIVAS_CI;Password= RAMNIVAS_CI;Persist Security Info=True;";
            conn.Open();
```

But getting the following error:

```
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
```

Although I have already installed it.

I have been able to connect to that server using Oracle Sql Developer. The settings are :
[image: Oracle SQL Developer Settings]
The TNSNAMES files is like this:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: F:\app1\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCLWEX1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle-db.newvisionsoftware.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = ORCLWEX1)
    )
  )

ORCLWEX2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle-db2.newvisionsoftware.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = ORCLWEX2)
    )
  )

ORCLWEX3 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.206.0.23)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = ORCLWEX3)
    )
  )
```

I have been told to use the last one: ORACLEWEX3.
I know there is some problem in the connection string and would be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Do you have more than one clients installed?

Comment: That I dont know, but I am able to connect to ORACLEWEX3 using SQL developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use 'Persist Security info' if you're using username/password.  Take a look at:
http://connectionstrings.com/oracle
for more examples.

Additionally, you could try using Oracle's own .net provider:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html
see if that works better for you.

Comment: Bro I used the same connection string with Oracle's own .net provider and this time the connection was successful. Will update u more later. Thanks !